# Convert gregorian datepicker to persian datepicker in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

How can I convert Gregorian datepicker to persian datepicker in Swift language ?

```
func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = NSCalendarIdentifierPersian

    dateOutlet.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)

}
```

I changed date format to`NSCalendarIdentifierPersian` but there isnt any change in datepicker?

Comment: you are changing date format of NSDateFormater not date picker btw

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the `calendar`, not the `dateFormat`:

```
dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierPersian)
```

You would also have to set the `locale` property if you want the language to change:

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fa_IR")
```

Also, as the comment on the question notes, you're working with an `NSDateFormatter`, not a `UIDatePicker` in your code.  Fortunately the answer is still correct; `UIDatePicker` also has a `calendar` property that you would set to accomplish this goal.

Comment: thanks for answering I understand and add calendar to my dateickerView, its worked but language of datepicker is not change to persian is there any way to change language?

Comment: Is your device in persian?  It should show in whatever locale the device/simulator is set to.  If you want to override the device/simulator locale, you have to set the `locale` property.  I will update my code example.

Comment: Apple does not support persian language, so there is no way to use persian as locale.

Comment: can i set globally. my app is old and I have big project.. and I have used calendar so many places.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change the default locale to something that isn't what the device is set to.  Your best bet is probably to make a function (perhaps in an extension on Calendar if you're using Swift) that creates the calendar and sets its locale and use that everywhere you ned it.

Answer (score 4):

SwiftUI Sample :

```
 DatePicker("", selection: self.$mySelectionDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                        .environment(\.locale, Locale.init(identifier: "fa_IR"))
                        .environment(\.calendar,Calendar(identifier: .persian))
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3:**

As Charles A. Said `DatePicker` has a calendar property and you can use it to have persian datepicker or even :

```
datePicker.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
```

Comment: I got the current date but can't convert it to the persian date

Comment: To convert dates you can take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41039598/2101822 . Hope it helps.